# Trim Name in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am very new to MS Access. I have list of names like this in a column in my access and would need to trim the names like below.

**Names:**

```
  Clooney, George Timothy
  Willam Pitt, Brad
  Wilson, Larry
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  Clooney, George
  Willam, Brad
  Wilson, Larry
```

I need to have the first word before and after the comma. Also on top of this I need to add a space after comma.

Really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: I am very new to Access and seeking help. Sorry to tell that this I tried a lot and nothing helped me. `SELECT LEFT(UserName, INSTRREV(UserName, " "))`

Comment: Which version of Access you're using? It's useless to use tags like that, it's better to define the tag that exactly matches your environment

Comment: I am using access 2007. Sorry for the tag thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this using a User Defined Function. Something like this might be helpful. Copy the code into a Standard module and then compile it.

```
Public Function getFirstName(inputStr As String) As String
'********************
'Code Courtesy of
'  Paul Eugin
'********************
    Dim tmpArr() As String, retStr As String
    Dim iCtr As Integer, charPos As Integer

    'Strip the Input String to an Array.
    tmpArr = Split(inputStr, ",")

    'Loop through the Array
    For iCtr = 0 To UBound(tmpArr)
        'Find the position of the SPACE character
        charPos = InStr(Trim(tmpArr(iCtr)), " ")

        'If the position is not found, return the whole string
        If charPos = 0 Then charPos = Len(tmpArr(iCtr))

        'Append the result String
        retStr = retStr & Trim(Left(tmpArr(iCtr), charPos)) & ", "
    Next

    'Finally return the actual generated String
    getFirstName = Left(retStr, Len(retStr) - 2)
End Function
```

To use this in a immediate window, use it as,

```
? getFirstName("Wilson, Larry")
Wilson, Larry

? getFirstName("Clooney, George Timothy")
Clooney, George
```

This can also be used in a Query.

```
SELECT 
    yourTableName.yourFieldName, 
    getFirstName(yourTableName.yourFieldName) As NewFieldName 
FROM
    yourTableName;
```